# about linear time and constant time of queue implementation on java linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

if I maintain a reference of `the least added item` but not maintain a reference of `most recently added` item, then I will have constant time `"dequeue"` and linear time `"enqueue"`. so this is my program which implement queue in java linked list. I want to ask if this program maintains both least added item and most recently added item? so it's all constant time when I `"dequeue"` or `"enqueue"`? thank you!

add: I kinda agree with what first answer said, so I tried the debugging mode and it shows that the oldlast hasn't updated after last changed so it's still working... but from the reference theory I learned from uni, just like he said, it shouldn't work.. Anyone can tell me why it's not updated automatically?(my java version 1.8)

```
package tst;

public class linkedlsqueue {

    private class Node {
        String item;
        Node next;
    }

    Node first, last;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void enqueue(String item) {
        Node oldlast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            first = last;
        }
        else {
            oldlast.next = last;
        }
    }

    public String dequeue() {
        String item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            last = null;
        }
        return item;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.   It is constant for both cases.

It is a good idea to keep record of **both** `first` and `last` for linked list.
Someone call it `head` and `tail`.

If you maintain only one of `last` or `first`, you have to search another one by iterating `first` to `last` to find another one or vice versa - one by one element, which is O(n).

It is like you are in darkness.
You hand holds an end of a rope and you want to know where it will lead to.
I can't think other ways beside tracing that rope.  It takes O(n) to trace.

I prefer to use array[] though.
With array, it is like you have a map, a sun, and a super portal (random access).
 However, it is not in the scope of the question.

Comment: just a point: in a list, the tail is everything behind the head

Comment: @Daniel  Disagree.  After a quick search:  http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/queue-data-structure

Comment: hmm... when I first learnt haskell, I used to do recursions on lists like this: do something with the head and call the recursion to the tail (which was the rest of the list). I used to call last element as tail too, but then I thought it was wrong... maybe I should just accept both :)

Comment: @Daniel  Prolog also has definition like you said (tail=the rest of the list).  I just realize its meaning is scope-specific.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct, but the implementation is **wrong**.

Look at this:

```
public void enqueue(String item) {
    Node oldlast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = last;
    }
    else {
        oldlast.next = last;
    }
}
```

when you do `oldlast = last`, you **DON'T COPY** the `last`, you just pass `last` reference to `oldlast`.

During the whole process, `oldlast` will be whatever `last` is. And in the meanwhile, you **RESET** the values of `last` when you do `last = new Node()`.

if you just want to enqueue, the correct method could work like this:

```
public void enqueue(String item) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.item = item;
    if(isEmpty()){
        first = newNode; last = newNode;
        return;
    }
    this.last.next = newNode;
    this.last = newNode;
}
```

to copy the element correctly, you should do:

```
Node oldlast = new Node();
oldlast.item = String(last.item);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I kinda agree with what u said, so I tried the debugging mode and it shows that the oldlast hasn't updated after last changed so it's still working... but from the reference theory I learned from uni, just like u said, it shouldn't work...u can try it on the compiler too...

Comment: strange... maybe the compiler leaves the old Node at the memory and create the new one somewhere else

Comment: now I figured it out, he thinks that oldlast is the reference of the last, but last is also a reference of null at that time, so oldlast is just a reference of null, which is an alias of last. only in C++, "The pointer that point to a pointer" can work like that.